# How can I insert a PHP generated PNG image into my html?

Tags: php, image, png

I'm generating a png image using php that works here:

http://www.sidesay.co/BTC_spark.php

However I am attempting to then insert the generated png file into a table on a webpage (I'm unsure if that's terribly inefficient). I use the php line:

```
    echo "<td><img src=\"https:\/\/www.sidesay.co\/BTC_spark.php\" ></td>";
```

I get a broken image, but if I right click and select "load image" it works.

Should I instead first run the php file and save the image separately before destroying it? If so, how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are you using to generate the image?

Comment: Oh. I suggest you to generate the image first, save it to a temporary file, and display it in the image. Also, you can generate images using PHP's inbuilt image processing library, GD.

Answer (score 0):

Your BTC_spark.php script is outputing HTML itself:

```
<html>
<body>
<img src='/libraries/Sparkline/sparkline.php?size=80x20&data=2,4,5,6,10,7,8,5,7,7,11,8,6,9,11,9,13,14,12,16&back=fff&line=5bb763&fill=d5f7d8' />
</body>
</html>
```

Change it to just output the img src:

```
/libraries/Sparkline/sparkline.php?size=80x20&data=2,4,5,6,10,7,8,5,7,7,11,8,6,9,11,9,13,14,12,16&back=fff&line=5bb763&fill=d5f7d8
```

... and then in your main script, stick this output in a variable:

```
$mypic = file_get_contents('./BTC_spark.php');
echo '<td><img src="'.$mypic.'"></td>';
```

Comment: Hi FoulFoot. I've just  tried to do this but it seems that "get_file_contents" is grabbing all code from "BTC_spark", which uses a library, and outputs the code onto the screen using the image tag. So I don't get an image. Perhaps I've misunderstood how to manage the output string you suggested. Should it be "echo /libraries/Sparkline/sparkline.php?size=80x20&data=2,..." I'm unsure how to get it to simply "output the img source".

Comment: I got it going by using your varilable above like this: ` $mypic = 'https://www.sidesay.co/libraries/Sparkline/sparkline.php?size=80x20&data=2,4,5,6,10,7,8,5,7,7,11,8,6,9,11,9,13,14,12,16&back=fff&line=5bb763&fill=d5f7d8';`. I really wanted to avoid sending all that data with my folder structure down into the webpage, whch can be inspected. Is there another way to push the image through? thanks.

Comment: You haven't said whether you have access to BTC_spark.php and can edit it.  If you can edit it, instead have it just set a variable, $mypic = '/libraries/Sparkline/sparkline.php?size=80x20&data=2,4,5,6,10,7,8,5,7,7,11,8,6,9,11,9,13,14,12,16&back=fff&line=5bb763&fill=d5f7d8'.  Then include this file from your main script.  The $mypic variable will then be set to what you need.